# Backbone model listener stops working as soon as the model is saved

Tags: backbone.js

In the initialize function of my backbone View, I created the following listener:

```
this.listenTo(this.model.get('clusters'), 'add remove', this.saveChanges);
```

This successfully causes my saveChanges function to be called the *first* time a model is added/removed from the 'clusters' Collection.  There's only one line in that saveChanges function:

```
this.model.save();
```

Once that is invoked, adding/removing clusters no longer invokes the "add" or "remove" event.  Why would saving the model destroy the listener?   Can that be prevented, or is there a way to re-establish the listener?

Or is there something fundamental I'm not understanding about Models and/or Collections...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break down your code:

You write

```
this.listenTo(this.model.get('clusters'), 'add remove', this.saveChanges);
```

Which is equal to

```
var clusters = this.model.get('clusters');
this.listenTo(clusters, 'add remove', this.saveChanges);
```

Now I only assume that after you get that event you `set()` a new `clusters` object inside your model.

The issue here is that your view still listens to events from that same old `clusters` object, which is not relevant anymore - your model deals with another object!

Another case could be that Backbone clears your view's event handlers from its model when it's being `remove`d.. Could easily answer for sure if you'd share the whole code.

Comment: Indeed, saving the model causes its "parse" function to be invoked, which I notice is setting a new value for "clusters" (I didn't write this code, just trying to understand and improve it).  Thanks for the tip!  I still need to figure out how/why parse is doing what it's doing, but at least I know now the listener is behaving as I thought it should...